# Clear database connection made via DAO.Database in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, dao

I'm making an ODBC Connection to an Oracle database in VBA using DAO Driver, however the last connected user to database is preserved for some time and it overwrites the new given credentials. Below is a code snippet related to the issue. It's any way to refresh or update the database object?

```
dim DB as DAO.Database    
dim DBName as String
          dim Datenbank_BuildConnectionString  as String
                DBName = "TNS database"

            Datenbank_BuildConnectionString = "ODBC" & _
                                                    ";DSN=" & "database name" & _
                                                    ";Uid=" & "adada" & _
                                                    ";Pwd=" & "password"

            Set DB = DAO.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(DBName, dbDriverNoPrompt, True, Datenbank_BuildConnectionString)


             Call DB.Close
              Set DB = Nothing
```

Regards,

Comment: I can't see `DB` declaration.. what have you declared it as?

Comment: Dim DB as DAO.Database. I have updated alos into Code snippet. Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105927/open-close-ado-connection). I suspect you are not actually closing the connection